# What does the "k" metric mean in the "sa" output?

Tags: process, cpu

From `man sa`:

```
k       cpu-time averaged core usage, in 1k units
```

My questions:

1. How is it calculated?
2. What is the significance?

Comment: Not sure how your man page is structured but the line immediately after that one on my system says "kilo-core seconds." I was able to find [this blog post](https://risboo6909.livejournal.com/84090.html) written by someone trying to figure out the same thing and he made some progress. He only ended up with a really tentative explanation though.

Comment: From looking at the 4.3BSD source, it looks like it takes the sum of (CPU time * average memory usage in KB) for every process in the accounting file and divides it by the sum of CPU times for all the processes.